# Disable constraints temporary in SQL server

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to copy all data from one database to another one, but I have many problems with foreign keys which cannot be inserted that easily. I would like to disable foreign keys, insert data, and then enable them again. What is the easiest way to do that?

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- disable the check_sale constraint in the employee table
ALTER TABLE employee NOCHECK CONSTRAINT check_sale

-- enable the check_sale constraint in the employee table
ALTER TABLE employee WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT check_sale
```

if your script span multiple tables you can retrieve all the constraints and disable all of them.

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
GO
```

http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/General/using_constraints.htm

Comment: This will leave them in an untrusted state. You need to ensure to use the `WITH CHECK` option so the query optimiser can use them. c.f. [13 Things You Should Know About Statistics and the Query Optimizer](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/) points 9 and 10.

Comment: It's obvious that the data would be invalid, he must do clean ups then enable them.

Comment: The way you re-enable them is the problem though. More details here http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1539